# NHibernate ORs using QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to create a simple select with an OR clause using NHibernate 3.3 using `QueryOver`. So for a simple select like:

```
Select x,y,z from myTable where x='one' or y = 'two' or z = 'three'
```

I've come up with this:

```
IList<MyTable> list = session.QueryOver< MyTable >()
.WhereRestrictionOn(
   Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.On< MyTable >(tab => tab.x == "One"),
                   Restrictions.On< MyTable >(tab => tab.y == "Two") )
 );
```

It doesn't compile and TBH I suspect I'm going in the wrong direction any way.

Comment: Can you give us the compilation error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax should solve it

```
var list = session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Where(
        Restrictions.Or(
          Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(tab => tab.x), "One"),
          Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(tab => tab.y), "Two")
        )
    )
    .List<MyTable>()
```

In case we want more, `Disjunction` is our way to multiple OR:

```
var list = session.QueryOver<MyTable>()
    .Where(Restrictions.Disjunction()
      .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(tab => tab.x), "One"))
      .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(tab => tab.x), "Two"))
      .Add(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Property<MyTable>(tab => tab.x), "xxx"))
    )
    .List<MyTable>()
```

Comment: Thanks, it certainly works for two columns - how do I add the third? (the z='Three')?